# Matlab code for creating the function

Tags: matlab

Matlab code for creating the function $y:[-10,10] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by
$$y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0 & x \leq -10^{-6}\\
x+10 x^9& -10^{-6}<x< 10^{-6}\\
x&x \geq 10^{-6}
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Just use if-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for this simple function.

```
function y = my_fun(x)

  if x<=-1e-6
    y =0;
  elseif x>-1e-6 && x<1e-6
    y= x+10*x^9;
  elseif x>=1e-6
    y = x;
  end

end
```

Comment: Error: File: my_fun.m Line: 4 Column: 1
Function definitions are not permitted in this context.  any remedy for?

Comment: Did you save this function as a separate m-file?